# Is there a way to check the type of an input, then loop back to the input if the type is incorrect?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def set_values():
    loopCtrl = 1
    while loopCtrl == 1:
        loopCtrl = 2
        juvenilePopulation = int(input("Enter the population of the juvenile greenfly (1000s) > "))
        if not isinstance(juvenilePopulation, int): loopCtrl = 1
        juvenileSurvivalRate = float(input("Enter the survival rate of juvenile greenfly (decimal) > "))
        if not isinstance(juvenileSurvivalRate, float): loopCtrl = 1
        adultPopulation = int(input("Enter the population of the adult greenfly (1000s) > "))
        if not isinstance(adultPopulation, int): loopCtrl = 1
        adultSurvivalRate = float(input("Enter the survival rate of adult greenfly (decimal) > "))
        if not isinstance(adultSurvivalRate, float): loopCtrl = 1
        senilePopulation = int(input("Enter the population of the senile greenfly (1000s) > "))
        if not isinstance(senilePopulation, int): loopCtrl = 1
        senileSurvivalRate = float(input("Enter the survival rate of senile greenfly (decimal) > "))
        if not isinstance(senileSurvivalRate, float): loopCtrl = 1
        birthRate = float(input("Enter the birthrate of the greenfly > "))
        if not isinstance(birthRate, float): loopCtrl = 1
```

I have this admittedly ugly chunk of code, that currently just asks for a bunch of inputs, assigns it to variables, and then checks the type of the variable, before looping back around to the top. What I really want to achieve is for the code to loop back to the input statement that had the incorrect input rather than the beginning, but in a way that is more pythonistic than a ton of while loops.

Comment: @Dev I had thought about it, but I was stumped on how to actually implement it. Have you any tips/guidance on how I could start?

Comment: maybe you could have a list of those variable names before the while..and if the input is correct you could pop those out.. and during each while loop, get only the input values of the variables that are inside the list only!! so by this you make sure you don't go and ask the user to input the correct inputs again

Comment: @Kulasangar would that not cause a problem due to the phrasing of each question, and the differing variable names?

Comment: oh the variable names would differ? in that case it would not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your calls to `input` with a function like this:

```
def get_value(prompt, validator):
    while True:
        try:
            return validator(input(prompt))
        except ValueError as err:
            print(f"  Invalid value, please try again: {err}")
```

You would call it like this:

```
juvenilePopulation = get_value("Enter the population of the juvenile greenfly (1000s) > ", int)
juvenileSurvivalRate = get_value("Enter the survival rate of juvenile greenfly (decimal) > ", float)
```

Running the above code looks something like this:

```
Enter the population of the juvenile greenfly (1000s) > foo
  Invalid value, please try again: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'foo'
Enter the population of the juvenile greenfly (1000s) > 1.1
  Invalid value, please try again: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.1'
Enter the population of the juvenile greenfly (1000s) > 12
Enter the survival rate of juvenile greenfly (decimal) > bar
  Invalid value, please try again: could not convert string to float: 'bar'
Enter the survival rate of juvenile greenfly (decimal) > 0.1
```

---

Note that in this example we're using basic types like `int` and `float` for validation, but you could just as easily pass in a custom function. For example, if the survival rate needs to be between 0 and 1, you could write:

```
def validateSurvivalRate(v):
    v = float(v)
    if not 0 < v < 1:
      raise ValueError("surival rate must be between 0 and 1")
    return v

juvenileSurvivalRate = get_value("Enter the survival rate of juvenile greenfly (decimal) > ", validateSurvivalRate)
```

Which would look like:

```
Enter the survival rate of juvenile greenfly (decimal) > foo
  Invalid value, please try again: could not convert string to float: 'foo'
Enter the survival rate of juvenile greenfly (decimal) > 1.1
  Invalid value, please try again: surival rate must be between 0 and 1
Enter the survival rate of juvenile greenfly (decimal) > -4
  Invalid value, please try again: surival rate must be between 0 and 1
Enter the survival rate of juvenile greenfly (decimal) > 0.4
```

Comment: Sure, but it will be converted to a `float` (so if you enter `2`, the return value would be `2.0`).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. I'm not sure this is the best practice but you reuse code this code. you can add extra datatypes also

```
def process_values(input_string, input_values, data_type):
    try:
        if not isinstance(eval(input_values), data_type):
            input_values = input(input_string)
            process_values(input_string, input_values, data_type)
    except NameError:
        print('Invalid input')
        input_values = input(input_string)
        process_values(input_string, input_values, data_type)


input_strings = ['Enter the population of the juvenile greenfly (1000s) > ',
                 'Enter the survival rate of juvenile greenfly (decimal) > ',
                 'Enter the population of the adult greenfly (1000s) > ',
                 'Enter the survival rate of adult greenfly (decimal) > ',
                 'Enter the population of the senile greenfly (1000s) > ',
                 'Enter the survival rate of senile greenfly (decimal) >'
                 'Enter the birthrate of the greenfly > '
                 ]

data_types = [int, float, int, float, int, float, float]

for input_string, data_type in zip(input_strings, data_types):
    input_values = input(input_string)
    process_values(input_string, input_values, data_type)
```

here i have handled errors also. if you need more exceptions condition you can add it there.